# Упаковать экземпляр класса в json

Tags: c#, .net, json, cookie

У меня есть экземпляр класса с куками. Я хочу сохранить его как json, а затем использовать позже, распаковав по такому же принципу. Проще говоря мне нужно передать экземпляр класса между сессиями. Как это сделать?

Comment: Сериализовать ?

Comment: @tym32167 Да, я просто не знал как это называется). Оформите как ответ, плюсану вам в карму)

Comment: @Stepan да тут на ответ не тянет, одно слово всего. Пусть будет дубликат